# Get tags for a specific post type

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to query the WordPress database to get the post tags for a specific post type.

So far I have this, which is giving me all the tags, but I'm not sure how to limit this to a specific post type, or if that is possible.

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM wp_terms";
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

foreach ( $myrows as $myrow ) 
{
    print_r($myrow);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to limit your queries, you can use the [WHERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29) clause, i.e.

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM wp_terms WHERE *post_type*=*typeyouwant*";
```

It's also possible to use the [LIKE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php) clause, but that results in very slow queries.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Seemed to return nothing. 
As far as my understanding goes I think I need to find out how the tags are associated with the posts.
I thought if I can get all the post IDs for the post type I want, then can I select the tags based on the post IDs?

Comment: You'll need to replace the variables in asterisks to the correct ones for your database.  Posting a sample of your database would help

Comment: It's just the standard WordPress database. The tag names or in the wp_terms table.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WP's database (I'm a Joomla guy myself), but `post_type` should be replaced with the column name (I guessed `post_type`) and `typeyouwant` should be replaced with the post type that you want.  Remember to quote it if you're looking for a string.